# mapbox-gl-draw in react and typescript

Tags: typescript, mapbox-gl, react-typescript

I'm (unsuccessfully) attempting to use mapbox-gl and mapbox-gl-draw in a react + typescript application.

Basically, the documentation at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/ exposes examples in pure js.
Also the example at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw#typescript seems not to deal with a react (functional) component.

Is there a way to use mapbox-gl and mapbox-gl-draw with react and typescript? If so, can an example be provided?

Answer (score -1):

In the latest version of **react-map-gl** they have added compatibility with the mapbox-gl-draw library:
https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/whats-new

You can use their example for the DrawControl component:
https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/blob/7.0-release/examples/draw-polygon/src/draw-control.ts

and then modify it based on how you want to pass it to your Map component.